# How do I add an OnClick to a LazyColumn text in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: onclick, android-jetpack

I just made a LazyColumn and put texts, but to those texts I want to add an OnClick attribute so that when clicking on each text in the list it calls a different phone number. For example: I want if I press where it says "first" the app call a phone number (the number that I put in the code, I don't want it to call a number that I must put when I use the app), and if I press where it says "second" the app call another phone number. I am working with Jetpack Compose, can you help me please? This is what I did so far:

```
   @Composable
fun Hacerllamada(){
val intent = Intent (Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("tel: ")
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Columna()  {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Gray)
    ) {
        item{
        Text(
            text = "primero",
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)

        Text(text = "segundo",
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)

        Text(text = "tercero",
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)}
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#get-click-position might help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Hacerllamada()` should not be a `@Composable`, just a normal method. Then you could add `clickable` to the modifier of your Text composable. Something like this

```
fun makeACall(context: Context, phoneNumber: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("tel: $phoneNumber")
    //make sure you have permission to make a call
    startActivity(context, intent, bundleOf())
}


@Composable
fun Columna() {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Gray)
    ) {
        item {
            PhoneNumber(title = "primero", phoneNumber = "11111")
            PhoneNumber(title = "segundo", phoneNumber = "22222")
            PhoneNumber(title = "tercero", phoneNumber = "33333")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PhoneNumber(title: String, phoneNumber: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Text(
        text = title,
        fontSize = 32.sp,
        color = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { makeACall(context = context, phoneNumber = phoneNumber) },
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: many thanks!! It has helped me, now I am missing what you told me about the permit, I'm going to look for that

Comment: @LEMILEMI have a look at Accompanist Permission: https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/ the permission you need is android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE